# Can I hide my backlink profile from my competitors?

Tags: links, backlinks

If you are ranking high then competitors try to check your backlinks and just go on creating links from where you have created.
Is there any method to hide links from competitors?

Comment: I think the question is clear.  Maybe the answers is just "no",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can 
if you have control over the other website that has backlink to you .. let's say your own PBN you can stop backlinks scrapping bots like ahrefs Moz semrush

if you don't have that option you can use free redirect services like bit.ly and other similar services they transfer the authority and hide your backlink origin.

of course, I am talking over here about backlinks you intend to build or you have access to it but if you had meant all your website backlinks profile that would be something really hard to do.

also, you can't use this technique extensively otherwise you will make google suspicious